# Ember.js assign action to a component inside component's js file

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a bootstrap button group which is dynamically created. So I created a button component which has a different icon and text.

For now I have assigned the action to the span inside the button.

**sample-component.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'button',
  actions:{
    triggerStatus:function(){
        this.sendAction('triggerStatus',this.get('dataId'),this.get('type'));
    }
  },
  didInsertElement: function(){
    //is it possible to assign action here
  }
 }
```

**sample-component.hbs**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{icon}}" aria-hidden="true" {{action "triggerStatus"}}></span>
```

I tried `this.set('action','triggerStatus')` inside `didInsertElement` but it didn't work out.
Can someone suggest me how to assign a action to a component within the javascript file itself? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Just wondering why it is you are looking to set the action in the component js instead of the hbs file?

Comment: @PhilHauser I am creatina button toolbar in which bootstrap doesn't allow a `div` within a btn-group. I can modify the css but, just curious to know whether we can assign action inside js file.

Comment: AFAIK the `{{action}}` helper is the only way (its definitely the way ember wants you to do it) to add events to your objects without just sacking off the `{{action}}` handler all together and using plain JS to bind events. For example in a few cases I use jQuery in the `didInsertElement` hook to bind user events instead of using embers `{{action}}` helper

Comment: `Handlebars.compile()` ?? Havnt tried it. Will let u know if it works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution for the problem. The solution was very simple just we can add a `click` handler inside the component and from there we can invoke `sendAction` method. Please find the example code snippet below

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'button',
  //rewrite the following action to
  /*actions:{
    triggerStatus:function(){
      this.sendAction('triggerStatus',this.get('dataId'),this.get('type'));
    }
  }*/,
  //to a component click handler
  click: function(){
    this.sendAction('triggerStatus',this.get('dataId'),this.get('type'));
  }
}
```

and removed the action from the `span` tag in the sample-component.hbs file

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{icon}}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Now each button in the button group have the different action based on the type